# Is it possible to use CV_GUI_EXPANDED flag in Python?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am new to opencv with python. I have used the flag CV_GUI_EXPANDED flag with opencv in c++. But after shifting to python, I am not able to use this flag. Is it not there in python version of opencv?

I am using the opencv available via anaconda and python 3.
Is there any other simple way to view the x, y coordinates and the r,g,b values of the points in a displayed image by hovering the mouse cursor over it, in python (as was possible with the use of the CV_GUI_EXPANDED flag in c++)??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Look at [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow) documentation:

If you showed code I could apply to your situation, but to answer a general question with a general answer, yes it is possible, CV_GUI_EXPANDED is supported in C, C++ and Python.

Comment: Just a side note... you may need to have your opencv compiled with Qt, since the expanded part is done with Qt, if not I think it doesn't complain but doesn't show the new things

Comment: I saw this documentation, I have been able to use the CV_GUI_EXPANDED in C++ version of my code. But it is the python version that does not work with this flag. This is the line of code I am using   >>>      cv2.namedWindow( 'Activation Layers', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.CV_GUI_EXPANDED )
And I get the error 'AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_GUI_EXPANDED''. Also how do I get the QT compiled with opencv in python using anaconda? The opencv that I am using is installed inside anaconda.

Comment: The documentation doesn't explain how to use CV_GUI_EXPANDED with python. There is no need for code for this question. Your answer gives hope but is no help and I think it should be comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the flag: WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED
Try to invoke the window by using:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Frame", flags=cv2.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)
```

You can then display the image with

```
cv2.imshow("Frame", img)
```

This will show you a statusbar on the bottom of the window with x, y coordinates and the r,g,b values of the points you hover

Comment: Thanks for help Nice try Lennart!! Please use comments to communicate anything other than concrete answers!